# Customizing Android checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, custom-controls

I am trying to partially change the images for Android's checkboxes. Following the tutorial [here](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html), I have done the following experiment:

```
<CheckBox
  android:checked="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<CheckBox
  android:checked="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:button="@android:drawable/btn_check_on"
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background"/>    
<CheckBox
  android:checked="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:button="@drawable/cb_on"
  android:background="@drawable/cb_background"/>
```

For the third checkbox, I have copied the images **btn_check_on.png** and **btn_check_label_background.9.png** from Android's SDK to the project's **res/drawable** and rename them to **cb_on.png** and **cb_background.png**. While I expected the three checkboxes to have identical appearances, surprisingly, the third checkbox is larger than the first two.  Can anybody explain why?  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you only copied one resolution of the drawables.  You need to copy all of them (mdpi, hdpi,ldpi) to the appropriate res folder (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi)

Comment: Thanks. @Jokahero is also right -- the copy of the background image must be named with the .9.png extension. Actually one can do without the background image.

Comment: (1) There is still one unsolved issue: the SDK does not seem to contain any ldpi resources, so I have nothing to copy to the projects' drawable-ldpi. Copying mdpi to ldpi does not work. (2) For mdpi, it seems that I also need to copy from Android's drawable-mdpi to both the projects' drawable-mdpi *and* drawable, otherwise the checkboxes will not show properly for Android 1.5.

Comment: you probably won't need the ldpi images.  if you really wanted to, you could shrink your mdpi's using photochop or gimp

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming your image cb_background.png in cb_background.9.png

.9 means that the image is a nine-patch image which is done to rescale itself automatically.

I think that why the third image is larger.

For more information about nine-patch: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: Thanks, but the modifications mentioned by @jkhouw1 are also needed.

Answer (score 1):

@Jokahero is right about the 9-patch, and @jkhouw1 is right about the resolutions. For checkboxes, you will also need to know about [StateListDrawable](http://file:///C:/usr/android-sdk-windows/docs/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).